# What is the fastest way to find the eigenvalues of a $50\times 50$ matrix?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am working on Continuous Galerkin Methods for Fluid Dynamics. As a part of this, I need to calculate eigenvalues of large matrices (for e.g. a $50\times 50$ matrix). I was wondering about any method which is faster than the usual way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the values in your matrix? Is the matrix sparse?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. What is the "usual way" for computng eigenvalues that you want to improve upon? Do these matrices have any special structure? Are the matrices related? BTW $50 \times 50$ is not especially large. My cheap little laptop can do about 150 eigenvalue calculations per second for matrices of this size.

Comment: @HansEngler. Thank you. The usual way is finding the characteristic equation and solving for its roots which involves finding the determinant of the matrix which is computationally laborious. And yeah i agree on the fact that there are many computer subroutines which can compute eigenvalues very efficiently. But I want to build my own function from scratch. These matrices do have a special structure. They are sparse and symmetric and are formed by a global assembly of small matrices. eg:first matrix [2 1; 1 2]  second [2 1; 1 2]. Hence global assembly becomes [2 1 0; 1 4 1; 0 1 2].

Comment: @Maczinga The matrices are sparse and symmetric. I am sorry I didn't mention it in the question as I was looking for a generalized procedure.

Comment: Did you try the Arnoldi method? Or better (for sparse matrix) the Lanczos method?

Comment: @shekhar - are these matrices tridiagonal or banded diagonal? In all these cases there are efficient and clever methods available. Setting up the characteristic polynomial and finding its roots is NOT, I repeat NEVER EVER the appropriate way to find the eigenvalues of a matrix of this size. It's been known for a long time that that is (a) inefficient and (b) numerically poorly behaved.

Comment: @Maczinga Thank you for the suggestion. I will look into it.

Comment: @HansEngler Thanks for the help.